# Simplifying matrix product with one unknown variable

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I have to compute a product of 3 matrices `D=ABC` with:

- A is a (1x3) matrix,
- B is a (3x3) matrix,
- C is a (3x1) matrix (and is equal to A', if it matters)

The result of this product is a simple value, and the calculation is very straightforward in R.

My problem is there is one unknown, namely `X`, inside `A` and `C`, and I would like to get the result as a formula: `D = ABD = f(X)`.

Is there any way I could achieve this with R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `D` as shown below where argument `B` is the square matrix and `A` is a function of `x` returning a vector.

```
D <- function(B, A) function(x) t(A(x)) %*% B %*% A(x)

# test
A <- function(x) seq(3) * x
B <- matrix(1:9, 3)
Dfun <- D(B, A)
Dfun(10)
## [1] 22800
```